# InDesign: how to find all numbers followed by a period

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep, regex

I have a list which consists of (goes up to 9):

```
 1.
 2.
 3.
```

And i want to make them:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

But, they all have a space before the number, I haven't found a regex to find all these occurrences, but not sure what to replace with:

```
 / [0-9]+\./gm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

- `\s(\d\.)` in the 'Find what' field. `\s` is the space and `(\d\.)` defines an expression made up of a digit and a full stop
- and `$1` in the 'Change to' field. this removes the space and keeps the previously defined expression

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! What does $1 signify?

Comment: Edited with some more details.

Comment: minor expansion/clarification: `(` and `)` are the group delimiters, and there can be multiple groups defined, referenced by order of appearance (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, . . . )